# Spark - Unable to use all the available workers during write operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write around 3.5 billion records from Teradata to S3 using Spark. I have 3 worker nodes, each containing 4 cores with 64GB of memory available for each core. Considering the amount of resources that I have, I am trying to load the data using 12 partitions (using the assumption that my optimal partition number is "4 cores x 3 workers").

I can see that the process starts off using all the 12 cores, but then reduces the number of cores to 3 within few minutes, and takes a lot of time to get completed. Is there any way I can utilize all the available cores and resources to get the data write completed faster, or is this Spark's way of telling me that "We don't need 12 of them, 3 is just fine!!"

I observed similar approach being followed by Spark when I used 3 workers with one core per worker and 10GB of memory, to load around 500 million records at one go. This time, Spark finished off the task in 2 of the 3 workers, finished them off, and then use one worker (thus one core) to load the entire data. And this took around 4 hours on an average every time.

Would be great to know on how Spark determines on how many cores to use for an operation and is there any way we can make use of idle cores to expedite the process.

**Update 1:** Have added the code that I am running, its pretty straightforward as we just need to dump the table data onto S3 in parquet format:

```
#Define SQL SELECT query for the table
query0 = *Teradata SQL Select query*

#Pass it on to the read operator
df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("user","batch user name")\
.option("password","batch user password")\
.option("url","jdbc:teradata://servername/LOGMECH=TD2")\
.option("dbtable",f"({query0}) as query")\
.option("partitionColumn","partitioning_column")\
.option("lowerBound", lower_bound_value)\
.option("upperBound",upper_bound_value)\
.option("numPartitions","Value based on the chunk of data I need to load for a run")

#Write out the results in partitioned format to S3 bucket
df.write.partitionBy("partition_column").mode("append").format("parquet").option("compression","snappy").option("fs.s3a.committer.name","partitioned").save("S3_file_path")
```

This code is put inside a loop and run for the required number of iterations.
For scenario 1, where I tried to load 3.5 billion records with 12 cores, there were no iterations: just a direct fetch and dump.
For scenario 2, I tried to pick around 250M records per iteration using 3 worker nodes, each having one core with 10GB of memory.

**Update 2:**
As per the suggestions mentioned in comments, have increased the partition size to 2x and 3x. Used S3A committer for performing S3 write, below is the configuration that I have used:

In spark-submit args:

```
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem\
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2001\
--conf spark.default.parallelism=2001\
```

In s3 file write operation

```
df.write.partitionBy("partition_column").mode("append")\
.option("maxRecordsPerFile",300000000)\
.option("fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")\
.option("fs.s3a.connection,maximum","100")\
.option("fs.s3a.multipart.size","30M")\
.option("fs.s3a.threads.max",20)\
.format("parquet")\
.option("compression","snappy")\
.option("fs.s3a.committer.name","partitioned").save("s3_file_path")
```

All these configuration changes did not yield any change in performance.

Just curious to know, Is there any way I can engage all of my executors to perform S3 write in parallel fashion (apart from S3A committer approach). As of now, what I observe is that only one worker performs a write at any given point of time. Is there any way we can make it parallelized?

Comment: Could you please share the code?

Comment: you should find out what those few workers are doing here. jstack will give you the stack traces. Spark may have good reasons, or you are potentially using an output committer which doesn't work properly with s3.

Comment: @IslamElbanna Added code that I am running for better understanding.

Comment: @stevel In the STDOUT log page for the workers, this is what I can see: Executors get assigned and start running task, connects to database, (few messages related to the fileoutput committer), then it shows a mesage saying "No need to commit output of task as needTaskCommit=false", Executor run finishes and the bytes of data sent to driver is shown". One common pattern that I observe is that one worker will have a message related to data spillage (UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 123 spilling sort data of 5GB to disk). This happens even if I pick up a relatively smaller dataset for execution.

Comment: @stevel The worker logs states that I am using org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter. The FileOutputCommitter Algorithm version is 1. Tried to use version 2 by specifying the required configuration 
in spark submit args, but I get an error while creating spark session.

Comment: How is the executors configurations you have? how many cores and memory per executor?

Comment: @IslamElbanna that is something that I am not fully sure about. Sorry, I'm still kind of finding my way through Spark actually. Based on what I see in the logs, it does not denote the number of executors with any numeric value (like Executor1, Executor2 etc). I assume that the minimum possible value might be 1 per worker, right? Any way that I can figure it out.

Comment: Ok, since this is a heavy IO job, and there is not much processing I'd try to increase the number of partitions to 2x or 3x and check the utilization and running time

Comment: if you are using s3 as a destination then you need to switch to the appropriate s3 committer for your spark installation (s3a committer or EMR spark committer). They are covered the spark and hadoop and emr docs, so go find the docs and start there. FileOutputCommitter takes O(data) time in job commit, with only one thread doing the work...

Comment: @IslamElbanna I have tried to increase the number of partitions to 2x and 3x, but I could see that both take roughly the same amount of time. To process around 260M records, both approaches took around 3 hours 20 mins or so.

Comment: @stevel I have set FileOutputCommitter version 2 as the default commiter via spark submit args. Have also used S3A configuration in my settings, you can find further information in my post. But all this hasn't given me any change in performance.

Comment: welcome to debugging. you are on your own now, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, finally found out the reason on why Spark wasn't able to utilize all its workers and do a parallel write. To enable parallel writes, the column on which partitioning is enabled needs to have higher variance. Which means you need to pick a column which has unique values in them.

If you pick a column like business date for partition, all the values present in that particular partition will have the same value for that field, hence this will end up to be a single worker task and the rest of the workers would terminate prematurely. Picking up a column with higher variation of values will enable Spark to distribute data across multiple workers. Also the above mentioned S3A configurations are handy for faster write.

Using this approach, I was able to utilize all my workers for parallel write and also avoid data spillage.